# FYI: New biblical archaeology magazine

Tags: discussion

For those interested in biblical archaeology, a new magazine has recently been published:
[Let The Stones Speak](https://armstrongmazar.com/magazine_issues/1), with potentially interesting topics.

E.g. this first issue includes [Top 10 Biblical Archaeology Discoveries of 2021](https://armstrongmazar.com/637-top-10-biblical-archaeology-discoveries-of-2021)

---

Note that the publication does have backing from a religious organization, but it isn't preachy, and doesn't solicit donations.
In fact, the print version is available totally free of charge.
Other than as a subscriber, I have no personal relationship with the organization.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the site, and found the January article on Jonah and the ancient city of Nineveh really worth-while. It caused me to return to a question on Jonah I had recently answered (on the Christianity site) and to drop that particular link in. https://armstronginstitute.org/639-is-the-book-of-jonah-entirely-ahistorical

Although *"For Your Information"* hardly constitutes a question, let alone warrant an answer, I feel it's worth while thanking you for the information and the link, as I hope to return to it in future. We likely would never have known about this new magazine had you not posted this. Thanks again.